# substring copying function in C results in seg

Tags: c, string, fault

My function subStr copies the "part"th part of a string(src) on another one (out). Despite everything seeming fine, when using the function i get a segmentation fault... Can anyone help? I have tried using valgrind to solve the problem but it isnt specific enough for me to find a solution.

*code pasted from link provided in a comment*

```
void subStr(char *src, char *out, int part) {           /*    subStr is a function that copies the "part"
                                                              substring of src to out and returns out's
                                                            address -- "parts" are strings seperated by spaces  */
    int i = 0, j = 0;

    while(part > 1) {

        while(*(src + i++) != ' ') {}                   // cycle through bytes of src

        part--;                                         // decrease "part" by one for every space found

    }                                                   // here we have reached the string we want to copy

    while((*(src + i) != ' ') || (*(src + i) != '\0'))  // copy till next space or end of string
        *(out + j++) = *(src + i++);

    *(out + j) = '\0';

}
```

Comment: This is the function https://pastebin.com/E9BANSnh

Comment: Can you show me how much memory are you allocating to src and output?

Comment: But can you show us entire code with main?

Comment: It doesnt work no matter the input from main. Despite that you can have my main:

Comment: int main() {

 char test[999];

 subStr("try number one", test, 2);
 printf("%s\n", test);

 return 0;

}

Answer (score 0):

while(*(src + i++) != ' ') {}                   // cycle through bytes of src

//you need to check if you out of *src;
either by (... && i < sizeof (src) && i < sizeof (out)); or by (... && ... != '\0')

Answer (score 0):

```
void subStr(char *src, char *out, int part) {
    int i = 0, j = 0;
    while(part > 1) {
        while(*(src + i++) != ' ' && *(src + i) != '\0' ) { }
        part--;
    }
    j = i;
    while((*(src + i) != ' ') && (*(src + i) != '\0'))
        *(out + j++) = *(src + i++);
    *(out + j) = '\0';
}
int main(int argc, const char** argv) {
    char s[] = "i like pie";
    char t[] = "i like cake";
    cout << s << endl << t << endl;
    subStr(s, t, 3);
    cout << s << endl << t << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

I included the point that user12315953 brought up in his answer.
output is as follows, which looks right to me:
i like pie
i like cake
i like pie
i like pie

Comment: in your main, i imagine the s and t char[] were declared as such : "char* s = "..." and same for t? c++11 doesnt allow conversion of literal like that, clang wouldve warned you, and this would have caused a segfault.

Comment: ps: i had assumed that you wanted the part "replaced". hence the addition of j = i. remove that and itll just output "pie"rather than "i like pie". wasnt sure what you were going for enitrely

Answer (score 0):

Problem is solved.. Just needed && instead of ||